# What happens? The output or the process linux,registers

Tags: linux, assembly, cpu-registers

What happens if you try to step into (si), the sysenter instruction?

Comment: You know what I do when I don't know what something will do. **I try it!** :-) (Obviously not for things like poking a sharp stick in my eye, or asking my wife's best friend out for a romantic interlude, but single-stepping into the OS is unlikely to be as dangerous as that).

Comment: lol mate read the question i said i couldnt figure it out which obviously means i have tried to do it before asking a question

Comment: @RohitPradeep: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer this question, you need to understand how `si` works.

How could it work? There are two ways I can think of:

1. either the debugger must set a (temporary) breakpoint on the next
   instruction, or
2. the debugger modifies processor state such that the processor will execute one instruction and stop (aka single-step).

Option 1. is complicated, because the instruction could be an indirect jump, e.g. `CALL (%eax)`, or a `RET`, and so the debugger might have to go to significant trouble to understand what that next instruction is.

All debuggers I am familiar with use option 2.

Now you can probably explain what you observe when you `si` over a `sysenter` (or a `syscall`, or a `int80`) instruction. The only other thing you need to know is that the kernel can't possibly allow the single-step mode once `sysenter` switches to the kernel mode (or else your entire system will freeze).